# Looking for an extremely shade-tolerant decorative plant

Tags: indoors, flowers, light

> direct sun light: 0h/day
> indirect sunlight: quite dim, the window is 10 meters away
> temperature: never freezing, never too hot

We tried a Ficus tree (was 50cm and in good health when moved there, survived several months) and a Pelargonium(20cm, not in perfect health but after only 2 days all it's leaves are yellowish).

No shade-seasoning by gradually applying less and less light has been performed. However it's winter so the day is pretty short anyway.

Are there any common plants that would thrive in near darkness?

---

@Jurp I never imagined indoors-ines goes beyond keeping warm in winter. I should post a question about that!

Epimediums looks somewhat exotic to be easily obtainable in Europe; doesn't matter as You said it won't work.

---

Here's an idea. Go to the forest. To the darkest part. Dig some weeds up and plant them home.

However I've done that several times with city weeds and they often die. I give them (moderate)sun, quality soil(instead of the construction rubble they were taken from), fresh air. And almost all wilt within a month.

Comment: You mention a window being 10m away - so are we to assume that you're looking for recommendations for an indoor plant?

Comment: Thanks, edited. I don't see how indoor-ism is too relevant to the question. The light levels are comparable to, say walnut shade all day with bushes all around so there's no reflected light bleeding.

Comment: i was also thinking about possible recommended plants. For example, epimediums might work outside but won't work inside.

Comment: Fake ones, if you want flowers. Mosses might put up with it, but 30 feet from a window is a long way without supplemental lighting. Go 30 feet into a cave and see what, if anything, is growing, perhaps...

Comment: Vorac, epimediums are mostly native to China, with some species found in the Mediterranean and Western or Central Asia, so I'd expect that there would be some available in Europe. A good groundcover is the hybrid Amber Queen, if you can find it - it's evergreen. Also, they're considered an aphrodisiac by some herbalists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Houseplants which tolerate dim light conditions do not usually produce flowers, but are kept for their foliage. Highly shade tolerant plants for indoors include *Zamioculcas zamiifolia'* commonly known as the ZZ plant; *Dracaena marginata*; *Hedera helix varieties* (Ivies or English ivy I think its called where you are) and *Aspidistra elatior* common name cast iron plant because it puts up with almost anything. Otherwise, most foliage houseplants do not appreciate direct sunlight,but may require reasonable or bright light levels,and it doesn't sound as if the position you want your plant in will provide this type of light.